# Generate ctags in C++ for types masked with using declarations

Tags: c++, templates, using, ctags

I am currently working on a project that employs a lot of C++ template metaprogramming. I have a lot of code that looks similar to the following:

```
template< class T >
struct MakeReferenceImpl{
    using type = T&;
};

template< class T >
using MakeReference = typename MakeReferenceImpl< T >::type;
```

I often use Vim and have found `gCtrl-]` to be indispensable for searching tags for symbols but noticed that aliased types generated via `using` do not receive their own tags (at least not by default). Is it possible to make ctags recognize `MakeReference` as its own type?

Comment: Unrelated, but `std::add_lvalue_reference` already exist.

Comment: Yep. I am aware. This was just the quickest example I could come up with. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Universal-ctags captures it well.

```
$ cat /tmp/input.cc 
template< class T >
struct MakeReferenceImpl{
    using type = T&;
};

template< class T >
using MakeReference = typename MakeReferenceImpl< T >::type;
$ ~/var/ctags-github/ctags -o - /tmp/input.cc 
MakeReference   /tmp/input.cc   /^using MakeReference = typename MakeReferenceImpl< T >::type;$/;"  t   typeref:typename:MakeReferenceImpl<T>::type file:
MakeReferenceImpl   /tmp/input.cc   /^struct MakeReferenceImpl{$/;" s   file:
type    /tmp/input.cc   /^    using type = T&;$/;"  t   struct:MakeReferenceImpl    typeref:typename:T &    file:
```

Comment: Works great. For future readers, I was able to install Universal-ctags on Mac with `brew install --HEAD universal-ctags/universal-ctags/universal-ctags`.